# prove that $f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{2^n}$ is continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

I refered that each fn is continuous because its the fraction of a continuous function by a number and so $f(x)$ that is the sum of continuous functions is continuous. Is it right?

Comment: Sum the series and inspect the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of two continuous functions is continuous, so you know that the k-th partial sum
$$
\:\sum _{n=0}^{k}\frac{\cos\left(nx\right)}{2^n}
$$
is continuous. Then use the fact that if $f_k$ is a sequence of continuous functions converging uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ is continuous. The uniform convergence can be proved by Weierstrass' M-test.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the Weierstraß M-test.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem. We are dealing with uniform convergence of a sequence of continuous functions.